# How to read specific rows and columns, which satisfy some condition, from file while initializing a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to look for an approach that will allow me to load only those columns from csv file which satisfy certain condition while I create a DataFrame.. something which can skip the unwanted columns because I have large number of columns and only some are actually useful for testing purposes. And also to load those columns which have mean > 0.0. The ideas is like we skip certain number of rows or read first nrows... but I am looking for condition based filtering for columns' names and values. 
**Is this actually possible for Pandas? To do things on-fly accumulating results first without loading everything into memory?**

Comment: depsnds on the condition i suppose, does it need to look at data within the column? or is it by say column name?

Comment: @Mit Just column names containing specific substring.. like 'node' in column name.. and ignoring others.

Comment: One approach might be to read the entire file and then, filter out the columns based on the condition.

Comment: @Mit The condition which looks for certain column values... say determining mean> 0.0 and selecting only those to load into memory.. is that possible too ? Because this will reduce the step of loading every column into memory and me then checking for mean.. so basically both the conditions.. if possible?

Comment: @Sajan That's exactly what has to be avoided, if possible. And suppose if this is the only way.. then how to filter based on names.. efficiently ?

Comment: in the usecols section, in pandas read.csv,  u could pass a lambda : ```lambda x:   "node" in x``` [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#filtering-columns-usecols)

Comment: Try reading the column names into a list and then, apply the condition to filter out the unwanted columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct/easy way of doing that (that i know of)!

The first function idea that comes to mind is: **to read the first line of the csv** (i.e. read the headers) then create a list using list comprehension for your desired columns :

```
columnsOfInterest = [ c for c in df.columns.tolist() if 'node' in c]
```

and get their position in the csv. With that, you'll now have the columns/position so you can only read those from your csv.

However, the second part of your condition which needs to calculate the mean, unfortunately you'll have to read all data for these column, run the mean calculations and then keep those of interest (where mean is > 0). But after all, that's to my level of knowledge, maybe someone else has away of doing this and can help you out, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think `usecols` is what you are looking for.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('<file_path>', usecols=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Comment: I don't know column names prior to loading the data... defeats the whole purpose. Suppose there are many columns... with large names... and I want to select and LOAD only those which contain string 'node' in them.... so **select:** data-activity-sample-node-read-1 BUT **ignore:** data-activity-sample-write

Comment: you could read the 1st line of csv and then do filtering based on phrase match in column headers. Reading one line in a csv should be efficient even if you have many columns

Comment: in the usecols section, u could pass a lambda : ```lambda x:   "node" in x```

Answer (score 0):

You could preprocess the column headers using the `csv` library first.

```
import csv
f = open('data.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
column_names = next(reader, None)
filtered_columns = [name for name in column_names if 'some_string' in name]
```

Then proceed using `usecols` from pandas as abhi mentioned.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=filtered_columns)
```